# Android how to get the only uri of Media Store Image?

Tags: android, path, uri, mediastore

I'm trying to get the uri and after parse into path of MediaStore image.
I do this to get the uri:

```
Uri img_uri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
```

And after with this function i convert uri in the path:

```
public String getRealPathFromURI(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
    Cursor cursor = null;
    try { 
        String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri,  proj, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null) {
          cursor.close();
        }
    }
}
```

But the result is that i have the path of the Media storage but with the first element.
For example: `/mnt/sdcard/Pictures/Boat.jpg`. But i want only `/mnt/sdcard/Pictures/`.

Please don't tell me to use join and split because isn't what i want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
String path = getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath();
```

to get the main directory in your app subfolder where you can put another directory, for example "Images" in this way:

```
String path = getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath() + "/Images";
File folder = new File(path);
if (!folder.exists()) {
   folder.mkdir();
}
```

So now with this:

```
String path = getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath() + "/Images";
```

you can access to this folder without problems.